# Replacement of whitespaces in a string using java on ubuntu server

Tags: java, linux, spring, ubuntu, window

i'm importing some data using csv files, i should read them line by line and assign values to a string then set every value to its fieldname in my object class.
my problem is that some fields are numbers and i need to replace whitespaces with an empty string so i can convert the string value to a new BigDecimal.

code in java:

```
 public static <T> T transformCsvToData(String ligneCsv, Class clazz, String[] fieldNames) {

        T t = null;
        try {
            if (!StringUtils.isBlank(ligneCsv)) {
                String[] listValues = ligneCsv.split(String.valueOf(DEFAULT_SEPARATOR));
                t = (T) clazz.newInstance();

                for (int i=0; i<fieldNames.length; i++) {
                    String fieldName = fieldNames[i];
                    String stringValue = listValues.length > i ? listValues[i] : null;

                    PropertyDescriptor pd = new PropertyDescriptor(fieldName, clazz);
                    Class fieldType = pd.getPropertyType();


                    // verifier qu'il existe une methode set
                    if (pd.getWriteMethod() != null && !"class".equals(pd.getName())) {

                        // recuperer la methode set
                        Method writeMethod = pd.getWriteMethod();

                        Object castedValue = null;
                        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(stringValue)) {
                            try {
                                stringValue = stringValue.trim();

                                if (fieldType == String.class) {
                                    castedValue = stringValue;
                                } else if (fieldType == Boolean.class) {
                                    castedValue = Boolean.valueOf(stringValue.toLowerCase());
                                } else if (fieldType == Date.class) {
                                    castedValue = new SimpleDateFormat(FORMAT_INPUT_DATE, Locale.FRANCE).parse(stringValue);
                                } else if (fieldType == Integer.class) {
                                    castedValue = Integer.valueOf(stringValue);
                                } else {
                                    stringValue = stringValue.replace(",", ".").replace("%", "").replace("\u00A0", "").replaceAll("\\s+", "").replaceAll(" ", "");
                                    if (fieldType == BigDecimal.class) {
                                        castedValue = new BigDecimal(stringValue);
                                    } else if (fieldType == Long.class) {
                                        castedValue = Long.valueOf(stringValue);
                                    } else if (fieldType == Double.class) {
                                        castedValue = Double.valueOf(stringValue);
                                    }
                                }

                            } catch (NumberFormatException | ParseException ex) {
                                castedValue = null;
                            }
                        }

                        writeMethod.invoke(t, castedValue);
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        return t;
    }
```

my dev local environment is running on windows and everything is working but when i build the artifact to test it on ubuntu server through jenkins. the functionality doesn't return the right result.

what can bee the difference between ubuntu and windows servers ? and how can i solve this issue ?
NB: i deployed the same war on windows server too and everything is working also.

Comment: When you say "doesn't return the right result", what *exactly* is wrong? Unexpected output? Error message?

Comment: please share an [mcve]

Comment: it return a numùber format exception because the whitespaces are still there. for exmaple, the string value='9 100 100', to convert it to a bigDecimal i need to replace its value to '9100100'.

Comment: You are shure that these are withspaces, not other unprintable character? You can remove `is the same replaceAll(" ", "")` as it is the same as `replaceAll("\\s+", " ")`

Comment: You could simply discard every character that isn’t valid for a BigDecimal:  `stringValue = stringValue.replace(",", ".").replaceAll("[^-.0-9]", "");`

Comment: @jens I tried using all space values to check if it's up to the whitespace value type.

Comment: BTW: Stop using outdated classes like `SimpleDateFormat` and `java.util.Date`. use the more modern `java.time` API

Comment: @MohamedLaajili *I tried using all space values* a non printable characcter is not a whitespace

Comment: yes, the proposition of @VGR solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are have between the numbers is not a blank, it is an unprintable character, so try to use
`stringvalue = stringvalue.replace(",", ".").replaceAll("[^\\d\\.]*", "")`
which replaces all character which are not numbers or a dot with nothing